# Приложение как сайт

Tags: php, html, вёрстка

делаю сайт аля steam, но появилась проблема с загрузкой файлов. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при загрузки приложения архив, или .exe файл не просто скачивался, а сразу переносился и устанавливался в какую либо папку, как собственно в steam. Проблема очевидна: с помощью веб сайта я это реализовать не могу, нужно приложение. Я хотел узнать, какие языки и инструменты требуются для такой "оригинальной" задумки, и отличается ли это от обычного web-программирования.

Comment: те, которые работают на стороне клиента, и позволяют пользоваться функциями браузера и ОС

Answer (score 0):

Один мой ответ удалили, вероятно посчитали вместо вас, что он вам не подойдет. Странно ведь, правда ? Вы его даже еще не успели прочитать, однако его удалили и решили что он вам не подойдет.

Тогда я вам другими словами объясню. Ваш вопрос весьма необъятен и ответ на него вы найдете лишь познав дзен программирования на вершине Айпетри в полночь на пеньке. 
Вот лично я так его и познал. Я про ответ на мой вопрос. Возможно ваш вопрос немного отличается и пенёк нужно выбрать другого цвета, но это пусть решают модераторы. Им лучше знать какого цвета пеньки выбирать.

Comment: Простите, что вы такое курите, и где оно растёт? На вершине Айпетри?